# Agregar un caracter al final de la consulta SQLSERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Necesito que en una consulta que por defecto me trae un digito entero, al final me coloque un caracter especial que en su caso es el **%**, habia intentado ejecutar esta consulta con la sentenca **Replace** , pero al intentar estructurarla me arrojaba un error.

Este es una consulta de mi Ejemplo:

```
DECLARE @Var NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Var = 70;

Replace(@var,'@var',@var%);
```

Mi sentencia de momento no me trae ningun resutado, pero al intentar tambien con **Substring** solo logre que eliminara el ultimo digito del resultado.

¿Como puedo lograr que se pueda añadir el signo de % al final?

Comment: Cuál es el error? [edit] la pregunta y añádelo. No resumas el error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT
concat(campoEntero, "%")
FROM
tablaEjemplo;

Answer (score 0):

Con esta consulta puedes convertir el dígito entero a string y luego concatenarle el caracter '%' al final del mismo:

```
select CONVERT(varchar(100), digitoentero) + '%' from tablaejemplo
```

Comment: ¿qué hace el código? puede que sea algo básico, pero si sólo dejas código las personas que no conozcan del tema, no van a saber porqué este código resuelve esta pregunta.